# multiple conditions within if statement NOT WORKING when using strings

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, error-handling

I am trying to check if colors contain either blue or green with red, and it is not working. Am I suppose to use the "or" operator inside of the pipe " | ". Or am I suppose to have the pipe outside of the parenthesis? I've tried everything and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
colors = 'red red'

if ('blue|green') and 'red' in colors:
     print(True)

>>> True
```

Comment: That pipe isn't an operator at all; it's just a character in a string.

Comment: when  use the or operator it still does not work. if('blue' or 'green' and 'red' in colors):

Comment: Did you read the answers to the linked duplicate?

Comment: Yes, however those use integer variables within the if statement, and I'm trying use strings for direct comparison.

Comment: The point is, `in` doesn't "distribute" over the Boolean expression. You have to be explicit: `if ("blue" in colors or "green" in colors) and "red" in colors`. The type of values you are looking for isn't relevant.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying! I'll try that out, thank you